# How could I disable particular items of a listview using C#.net?

Tags: c#

I've created a listview in C#.net with a small number of items in it. I want to disable some of the items of the listview.

I have go through each property of the listview, but I'm not getting the proper way to disable listview items.
Please help me!

Following is a code snipet:

```
private void lvTenderCode_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // setLoadModify1(lvTenderCode.Items[lvTenderCode.FocusedItem.Index].SubItems[0].Text, false);
    //clsSettings.setMDIChild(FrmList.Instance(), MainMenu.publicMDIParent);
    string ss;
    ss = lvTenderCode.Items[lvTenderCode.FocusedItem.Index].SubItems[0].Text;
    if (ss == "Material Requisition") {
        // FrmBoqOptionEntryNew sForm = new FrmBoqOptionEntryNew();
        // sForm.ShowDialog (); 
        // this.Close();
        //Variables.StrBoqMessage = "StrBoqTreeView";
        clssetting.Settings.setMDIChild(FrmMaterialRequisition.Instance(), FrmMainMenu.publicMDIParent);
        }
        if (ss == "Purchase Indent") {
            // FrmBoqOptionEntryNew sForm = new FrmBoqOptionEntryNew();
            // sForm.ShowDialog (); 
            // this.Close();
            //Variables.StrBoqMessage = "StrBoqTreeView";
            clssetting.Settings.setMDIChild(FrmPurchaseIndent.Instance(), FrmMainMenu.publicMDIParent);
        }
        if (ss == "Quotation") {
            // FrmBoqOptionEntryNew sForm = new FrmBoqOptionEntryNew();
            // sForm.ShowDialog (); 
            // this.Close();
            //Variables.StrBoqMessage = "StrBoqTreeView";
            clssetting.Settings.setMDIChild(FrmQuotationVoucher.Instance(), FrmMainMenu.publicMDIParent);
        }
        if (ss == "Purchase Order") {
            // FrmBoqOptionEntryNew sForm = new FrmBoqOptionEntryNew();
            // sForm.ShowDialog (); 
            // this.Close();
            //Variables.StrBoqMessage = "StrBoqTreeView";
            clssetting.Settings.setMDIChild(FrmPurchaseOrder.Instance(), FrmMainMenu.publicMDIParent);
        }
        if (ss == "Spot Purchase Order") {
            // FrmBoqOptionEntryNew sForm = new FrmBoqOptionEntryNew();
            // sForm.ShowDialog (); 
            // this.Close();
            //Variables.StrBoqMessage = "StrBoqTreeView";
            clssetting.Settings.setMDIChild(FrmSpotPurchaseOrder.Instance(), FrmMainMenu.publicMDIParent);
        } else if (ss == "Exit") {
            FrmsmallQuit sForm = new FrmsmallQuit();
            sForm.Location = new Point(600, 627);
            sForm.ShowDialog();
            if (FrmsmallQuit.strMsg == "YES") { Close(); }
            else { return; }              
        }
   }
```

Comment: Please define disable. Does removing them meet your needs?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d3c68d8a-89d3-4de6-b9f9-4d617ffdeb77/disable-item-selection-of-the-listview  check this

Comment: No i do not want to remove item i just want to show some of the items of listview on runtime and rest of the items can't access by user i mean to say i want to make disable .
Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by 'disabling' not showing, you should check the Filter option.

Make a CollectionView, then use the Filter property of that view.

For an example, see: [enter link description here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-filtering/)

Comment: Filter option of is there as properties of Listview?

Comment: I have go through your link but it doesn't satisfied my requirement,
i want to that some of the items is accessible in listview which means from those items i can able to open any form & some of the item can't be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a single property that lets you do this.

Typically, the approach is to handle the index changed event and immediately set the `Selected` property to false (i.e. giving the user the appearance of it being 'unselectdable'):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemselectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

```
private void ListView1_ItemSelectionChanged(Object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
       // If 'e' is the item you want to 'disable'
       e.Item.Selected = false;
    }
```

Comment: Okay thank you for your reply, but i want to disable item on load event is there anyway to do this?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: i mean to say that i want to disable listview item on load event

Comment: as i have mentioned above listview with number of items i want to show some of the items and rest of the item won't b accessible by particular user.
This is how i want to disable particular item of listview

Comment: Explain 'accessible'. What do you mean 'particular user'? These items need to be disabled by on individual users?

Comment: Yes on Individual users.

Comment: And, for the very last time, what do you mean disable list items? How should they appear? Behave? Clarify what you're talking about.

Comment: I am talking about how could i disable listview items .
the items should appear in the form which are required to show for eg.
1.MaterialRequisition
2.Purchase Indent
3.Purchase order these are the items of listview,
only item no 1. that is material requisition i can click and show relevant form. 
Rest of the items i.e. 2 & 3 can't allow to access.

Comment: I don't have even the slightest clue about what you're talking about. Think about it. Read what you've wrote in this thread so far and the assumptions you're jumping to in terms of what you expect us to know about the context of your problem. I'm not helping any further it's frustrating.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm lost (too).